# Retrieving all records from a table of openerp with mako templates

Tags: odoo, mako, openerp-7

I want to know how can i get all records of a table from my openerp 7 with mako templates(to show it in my report).
As far I know, in my mako template i have an iterable called objects which is a browse_record(suri.flete.items_recorrida, 1).

My question is how can i get all the records of the table "suri.flete.items_recorrida", and then only show in the report the items which values en_recorrida and finalizado are False.

In my mako template(flete_rep_webkit.mako):

```
    %for item in objects:
        <tr>
            <td>${item.descripcion}</td>
            <td>${item.origen.nombre}(${item.origen.direccion},${item.origen.localidad})</td>
            <td>${item.destino.nombre}, (${item.destino.direccion},${item.destino.localidad})</td>
        </tr>
    %endfor
```

In my parser .py file(flete_webkit.py)

```
import time
from report import report_sxw
from osv import osv

class flete_webkit(report_sxw.rml_parse):
    def __init__(self, cr, uid, name, context):
        super(flete_webkit, self).__init__(cr, uid, name, context=context)
        self.localcontext.update({
            'time': time,
            'cr':cr,
            'uid': uid,
        })        

report_sxw.report_sxw('report.webkit.flete_items_recorrida',
                           'suri.flete.items_recorrida', 
                           '/suri/flete/report/flete_rep_webkit.mako',
                           parser=flete_webkit)
```

In my view

```
<report auto="False" id="flete_webkit" model="suri.flete.items_recorrida" name="webkit.flete"  file="suri/flete/report/flete_rep_webkit.mako" string="Reporte prueba" report_type="webkit" />
```

In my .py file (flete.py)

```
class items_recorrida(osv.osv):        
    _name = "suri.flete.items_recorrida"
    _columns = {
        'name' : fields.related('descripcion', 'name', type="many2one", relation="suri.flete.items_recorrida", string='Descripcion',context="{'form_view_ref' : 'suri.flete.formulario_flete_items_recorrida', 'tree_view_ref' : 'suri.flete.arbol_flete_items_recorrida'}"),
        'estado' : fields.boolean('Estado', required=True),
        'descripcion' : fields.char('Descripcion', size=128, required = True),
        'documentacion' : fields.char('Documentacion', size=128, required = False),
        'origen': fields.many2one('res.partner.sedes','Origen', required=True),#FK->res.partner.sedes
        'destino': fields.many2one('res.partner.sedes','Destino', required=True),#FK->res.partner.sedes
        'pedido_por': fields.many2one('res.users','Pedido por', required=True),#FK->res.users
        'id_flete': fields.many2one('suri.flete.recorrida','Numero de flete',required=False),#FK->suri.flete.recorrida        
        'nota': fields.char('Nota',size=128,required=False),
        'proyecto': fields.many2one('suri.proyectos.proyecto','Proyecto',required=False),#FK->suri.proyectos.proyecto
        'dimension': fields.char('Dimension Estimada', size=128, required = False),
        'peso': fields.char('Peso Estimado', size=128, required = False),
        'fragil': fields.boolean('Es fragil?', required=False),
        'urgente': fields.boolean('Es urgente?', required=False),
        'en_recorrida': fields.boolean('Esta en recorrida?', required=False,),
        'finalizado': fields.boolean('Esta finalizado?', required=False,) 
    }

    _defaults = {
    'en_recorrida' : False,
    'finalizado' : False,      
    }

    _rec_name = 'descripcion'
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a method in parser that returns all the records where finalizado & en_recorrida are False

```
import time
from report import report_sxw
from osv import osv

class flete_webkit(report_sxw.rml_parse):
    def __init__(self, cr, uid, name, context):
        super(flete_webkit, self).__init__(cr, uid, name, context=context)
        self.localcontext.update({
            'time': time,
            'cr':cr,
            'uid': uid,
            'get_records': self._get_records,
        })       

    def _get_records(self):
        rc_ids = self.pool.get('suri.flete.items_recorrida').search(self.cr, self.uid, [('en_recorrida', '=',  False),('finalizado', '=',  False)])
        return self.pool.get('suri.flete.items_recorrida').browse(self.cr, self.uid, rc_ids) 

report_sxw.report_sxw('report.webkit.flete_items_recorrida',
                           'suri.flete.items_recorrida', 
                           '/suri/flete/report/flete_rep_webkit.mako',
                           parser=flete_webkit)
```

And in your mako  use it like this

```
%for item in get_records():
    <tr>
        <td>${item.descripcion}</td>
        <td>${item.origen.nombre}(${item.origen.direccion},${item.origen.localidad})    </td>
        <td>${item.destino.nombre}, (${item.destino.direccion},${item.destino.localidad})</td>
    </tr>
%endfor
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help, i really appreciate it! I've modified the code like you said, but it throws me this error in the debugger:  `File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mako/runtime.py", line 841, in _exec_template
    callable_(context, *args, **kwargs)
  File "memory:0xb10e82c", line 43, in render_body
    %for item in get_records():
TypeError: 'Undefined' object is not callable ` Any idea of whats going wrong?

Comment: don't forget to import your parser in `__init__.py`